# Connect Flask backend with the HTML page in order so that the Student Registration Form can function properly?

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, backend

When I put all the info for the student in the form and when I press the REGISTER button, the info does not register into the database and it does not direct me to the thank-you.html page where it thanks the student for registering?

The database is working but I think there's something wrong with the Flask code, can someone please help me?

`The HTML Code (StudentRegistration.html)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/StudentRegistration.css">
    <title>Student Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/submit_form" method="post">
      <div class="container">  
        <center>  <h1> Student Registeration Form</h1> </center>
        <hr>  
        <label> Firstname </label>   
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder= "Firstname" size="15" required />      
        <label> Lastname: </label>    
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" size="15"required />  
        <br>
        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>  
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required> 
      <div>  
      <label>   
      Course :  
      </label>    
      <select>  
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select your course</option>
        <option value="Animation">Animation</option>
        <option value="Social Media Marketing">Social Media Marketing</option>
        <option value="Web and App Design">Web and App Design</option>
        <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
        <option value="Video Editing">Video Editing</option>
        <option value="Video Games Development">Video Games Development</option>  
      </select>  
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
      </div>          
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

`Flask code (Register.py)`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/submit_form', methods=['POST'])
def submit_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Fetch data from the form
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']
        course_name = request.form['course']

        try:
            # Connect to the MySQL database
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                                  database='solarAcademy',
                                                  user='root',
                                                  password='P@ssw0rdMySQL',
                                                  ssl_disabled=True)
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            # Insert student data into 'students' table
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO students (name, lastname, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (firstname, lastname, email))
            student_id = cursor.lastrowid

            # Check if the course exists
            cursor.execute("SELECT course_id FROM courses WHERE course_name = %s", (course_name,))
            course_data = cursor.fetchone()

            if course_data:
                course_id = course_data[0]

                # Register student for the course
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO registrations (student_id, course_id) VALUES (%s, %s)", (student_id, course_id))
                connection.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('thank_you'))

            else:
                return "Course not found."

        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            return "Error: {}".format(error)

        finally:
            if 'connection' in locals() and connection.is_connected():
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()

@app.route('/thank_you')
def thank_you():
    return render_template('thank-you.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Does the `select` tag need a `name="course"` attribute?

Comment: Yeah I added it but it still didn't work, it gives me this error: Your file couldn’t be accessed It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Are you sure that the python script is working and the url is correct? Because if the page for example is /login it will take you to /login/submit_form

Comment: So yeah I changed both url from the html and python script into /login/submit_form but it didn't work but I think the problem might be from the post method, should I change it and add a get method?